# Swashbuckle and .Net core - How to return a empty body on error?

Tags: asp.net, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Im creating this following endpoint:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a new validation process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="order"></param>
    /// <response code="201">Campaing created successfully</response>
    /// <response code="400">An invalid request has been made. Check response for details.</response>
    /// <response code="406">A campaing is already in progress for this target for this requestor</response> 
    [HttpPut]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created, Type = typeof(ValidationProcessBase))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<string>))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable)]
    public async Task StartNewProcess([FromBody] StartValidationProcessOrder order)
    {
        //return null;
    }
```

I wish that the body of a `406` response code to be empty, like a `204`, but for some reason a "ProblemsDetail" is being declared instead...

can anyone pls tell me how to make that `406` body empty?

Comment: How is this a swagger or swashbuckle problem? does it not happen with other tool like postman or when you call your api from your client ? and 406 indicates a problem in the accepted header that's the reason problem details is included. i would suggest to analyze in which case you want to send 406 response.

Comment: im not 100% sure its a swashbuckle problem, but if your method returns a simple `Task`, the payload should be empty... and lets remember that a 406 with a status description "You cannot progress a cancelled project" is a valid response

Comment: You didn't ans the main ques here, did you get same response from other clients also or only from swagger ?